# WordPress Reserved Terms, any workaround?

Tags: slug

I noticed that "embed" is part of "reserved terms" so it automatically change my slug in embed-2. There is any solution to force it to "embed"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the list of reserved terms is there for a reason: to make sure WordPress core features relying on URL's work correctly, and to prevent conflicts with content or plugins.

Comment: Url rewriting can't help?

Comment: No, because reserved words are there because of the URL, and WordPress doesn't have filters to change any of the reserved words.